# transpose each matrix in an array of matrices without changing the order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

`x` and `y` contains 3 matrices of dimension 1*3,

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6], [1, 2, 3]])

y = np.array([[11, 22, 33], [44,55,66], [11, 22, 33]])

I want to make matrix multiplication between x and y, and hence y should be transposed i.e., each vector in y should be 3*1 and Z should be an array that contains the result of x[0]*y[0]' x[1]*y[1]' x[2]*y[2]'
```

How to transpose only each matrix without changing their orders in `x`? I tried `x_transposed = x.T` but it does a different thing

Comment: Specify what your expected output looks like, but "it do a different thing" is not very specific.

Comment: `x` is a (3,3) array.  The transpose of such a matrix is well defined, `[[1,4,1],[...]`.  It isn't 3 (1,3) arrays.  Do you understand the difference between shapes (3,), (1,3), and (3,1)?

Comment: Also, your matrices are the same size... you should already be able to multiple them.

Answer (score 2):

`x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6], [1, 2, 3]])` is a *two-dimensional* array, so you could say it contains three *vectors* of shape `(3,)`. To demonstrate this,

```
for v in x:
    print(v.shape, v)
```

prints:

```
(3,) [1 2 3]
(3,) [4 5 6]
(3,) [1 2 3]
```

For `x` to contain three matrices of shape `(1, 3)`, you need it to be a *three-dimensional* array, `x = np.array([[[1, 2, 3]], [[4,5,6]], [[1, 2, 3]]])`. Now, the same loop from above prints:

```
(1, 3) [[1 2 3]]
(1, 3) [[4 5 6]]
(1, 3) [[1 2 3]]
```

Then, you can transpose the second and third axes of this array with:

```
x_transposed = np.transpose(x, axes=(0, 2, 1))
```

This results in:

```
array([[[1],
        [2],
        [3]],

       [[4],
        [5],
        [6]],

       [[1],
        [2],
        [3]]])
```

---

To convert your original `x` into the three-dimensional array, you can add an axis in the middle of the two existing axes with:

```
x = x[:, None, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer if you actually showed the results you want, but I think you want to take the `dot` product of the row pairs:

```
In [15]: [np.dot(i,j) for i, j in zip(x,y)]
Out[15]: [154, 847, 154]
```

If you take time to actually read `np.dot` docs (the original matrix product function) you'll see it's quite happy to take 1d arrays as argument.

Another way to get the same values:

```
In [18]: (x*y).sum(axis=1)
Out[18]: array([154, 847, 154])
```

One row of `y` is (3,) shape (1d)

```
In [23]: y[0]
Out[23]: array([11, 22, 33])
```

Transpose of that doesn't change anything, since there's only one axis.  Transpose doesn't `add` a dimension:

```
In [24]: y[0].T
Out[24]: array([11, 22, 33])
```

If the array was 2d, (1,3), tranpose would make it (3,1), a 'column vector', which can also be created with:

```
In [25]: y[0][:,None]
Out[25]: 
array([[11],
       [22],
       [33]])
```

`dot` of the two (3,) produces a scalar:

```
In [27]: np.dot(x[0],y[0])
Out[27]: 154
```

`dot` of (3,) and (3,1) produces a (1,), array:

```
In [28]: np.dot(x[0],y[0][:,None])
Out[28]: array([154])
```

(a (1,3) with (3,1) would yield a (1,1)).

`dot(x,y.T)` (or with the `matmul` operator), produces a (3,3) array, with the desired 3 values on its diagonal:

```
In [30]: x@y.T
Out[30]: 
array([[154, 352, 154],
       [352, 847, 352],
       [154, 352, 154]])
```

A better way of getting this 'diagonal' is with `einsum`, specifying the dimension `j` that is the sum-of-products:

```
In [32]: np.einsum('ij,ij->i',x,y)
Out[32]: array([154, 847, 154])
```

`matmul/@` lets us treat the first of 3 dimensions as a `batch`, so by making the arrays (3,1,3) and (3,3,1), we get a (3,1,1) result:

```
In [33]: x[:,None,:] @ y[:,:,None]
Out[33]: 
array([[[154]],

       [[847]],

       [[154]]])
```

the (1,1) dimension can be `squeezed` out.

For 2d `dot/matmul` does a sum-of-products with the last dim of A and 2nd to the last of B.